# vuejs How to move v-slot references into a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I don't quite get how to move the `v-slot` data into a component.

Let's say I want to refactor the follwoing code:

```
        <template v-slot:item="data">
          <template v-if="typeof data.item !== 'object'">
            <v-list-item-content v-text="data.item"></v-list-item-content>
          </template>
          <template v-else>
            <v-list-item-avatar>
              <img :src="data.item.avatar">
            </v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-html="data.item.name"></v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle v-html="data.item.group"></v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </template>
```

How do I pass the data inside a new component? I tried it with `props` but the component wouldn't show up:

```
          <ListElementAvatar
            :item="data.item"
            :imgSrc="data.item.avatar"
            :title="data.item.name"
            :subtitle="data.item.group"
            :source="data" />
```

ListElementAvatar:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="typeof item !== 'object'">
      <v-list-item-content :v-text="item"></v-list-item-content>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <ListItemAvatar :imgSrc="imgSrc" />
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title :v-html="title"></v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle :v-html="subtitle"></v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ListElementAvatar",
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
    imgSrc: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    subtitle: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    source: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

What I want to achieve:
I'm trying to refactor the code, i.e. creating small components. The code in the first listing should be put inside a vue component, called `ListElementAvatar`. Because I want to reuse it later. When I want to reuse it, I just call  instead of the long code in the first listing.

Context:
https://codepen.io/thadeuszlay/pen/gOYevRZ?editors=1010

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to acieve.

Comment: @AdamOrlov I'm trying to refactor the code, i.e. creating small components. The code in the first listing should be put inside a vue component, called `ListElementAvatar`. Because I want to reuse it later. When I want to reuse it, I just call <ListElementAvatar /> instead of the long code in the first listing.

Comment: There may be no reason to pass both `data` and all its properties separately, btw, unless you plan to reuse this component in a different context.  It's more readable / efficient to simply pass `data` and grab the properties on the other side in the component.

Comment: @Dan has it's point. You are passing down `item` and later item's property. It'd be more clear to pass it as one object or separate them all :)

Comment: @AdamOrlov Generally speaking, if the properties are always grouped together by an object structure / class type, it's more readable and sensible to pass the object.  It becomes clearer when you imagine passing 100 properties for no reason instead of the object itself.

Comment: @Dan I agree. PS if your component needs 100 properties then it a hell of a component ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your component inside template with scoped-slot:

```
<template v-slot:item="data">
  <ListElementAvatar
    :item="data.item"
    :imgSrc="data.item.avatar"
    :title="data.item.name"
    :subtitle="data.item.group"
    :source="data"
  />
</template>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, that works. I tried it already. But I was looking for a solution where I can pass in data inside the new component, i.e. no template wrapper around.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Comment: I think moving `v-slot:item="data"` into `ListElementAvatar` like this: `ListElementAvatar v-slot:item="data"...` would work too. But Using template is more clear to me.

Comment: How exactly? Simply inserting v-slot:item="data" (next to other properties) won't work.

Comment: @thadeuszlay Hmm mayby it changed after version 2.6+ :-|